# AngularJS Material Design Tabs Transparent

Tags: angularjs, tabs, themes, angularjs-material

Does anyone know of a way to make the **md-tabs** of angularJs Material that holds the names (headers) of tabs to have a transparent background, I have tried all sorts with no success.

I believe this should be the default behaviour but for some reason it isn't.

I have also tried setting the theme colors, but both white and transparent colors can not be set on any of the properties:

```
<md-tabs>
   <md-tab label="Dashboard"></md-tab>
   <md-tab label="Events"></md-tab>
   <md-tab label="Tasks"></md-tab>
   <md-tab label="Guests"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the styles css,  I found this style: `.md-header` does it by setting the `background-color` property.

Comment: Would you be able to show code for how you achieved this? I am attempting to create a transparent toolbar and not having much luck myself